# Data transfer between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing a restaurant program. I'm having a problem. Now I will tell you the events that happen during product selection

**The application consists of two fragments. Activity name is 'MasaDetay'. FragmentOne name is 'MasaUrunler', FragmentTwo name is 'MasaAdisyon' **

**Actions in the 'MasaUrunler' fragment**

1. I bring the products from the database with Volley and I list them on the screen thanks to a RecycleView
2. I print the listed products and I choose the quantity, portion and properties of these products in another activity
3. I get all the data in the onActivityResult function
4. I am sending the data held in an array into another fragment

**In the 'MasaAdisyon' fragment, the following events occur**

5. I'm doing the LayoutManager events in **onCreateView** and I bind an **adapter** and **RecycleViewAdapter**
6. **I'm looking at the size of the array** in the **getItemCount** function in the **RecyclerViewAdapter**. ***In this step the new data does not come into RecycleViewAdapter***

**MasaUrunler Kotlin Codes**

```
var ADISYONLISTESI = ArrayList<AdisyonListesiBilgileri>()
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == 1){
            var gecici = AdisyonListesiBilgileri(
                    data?.extras!!.getDouble("MIKTAR"),
                    data?.extras!!.getDouble("PORSIYON"),
                    data?.extras!!.getSerializable("URUNANABILGILERI") as UrunBilgileri,
                    data?.extras!!.getSerializable("SECILENOZELLIKLER") as ArrayList<secilenOzellikler>,
                    data?.extras!!.getSerializable("OZELLIKLISTESI") as ArrayList<UrunOzellikBilgileri>,
                    0,
                    0,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            )
            ADISYONLISTESI.add(gecici)
            var bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putSerializable("ADISYONLISTESI",ADISYONLISTESI)
            var masaAdisyon = MasaAdisyon()
            masaAdisyon.arguments = bundle
            var fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
            fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.detach(masaAdisyon)?.attach(masaAdisyon)?.commit()
        }
}
```

**MasaAdisyon Kotlin Codes**

```
var adapter : MasaAdisyonListesiAdapter? = null
var ADISYONLISTESI = ArrayList<AdisyonListesiBilgileri>()
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    var thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_masa_adisyon, container, false)
    var args = arguments
    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    thisView?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.masaAdisyonListesiRecycle)?.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adapter = MasaAdisyonListesiAdapter(ADISYONLISTESI)
    if(args?.getSerializable("ADISYONLISTESI") != null){
        ADISYONLISTESI = args?.getSerializable("ADISYONLISTESI") as ArrayList<AdisyonListesiBilgileri>
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    thisView?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.masaAdisyonListesiRecycle)?.adapter = adapter
    return thisView
}
inner class MasaAdisyonListesiAdapter(_ADISYONLISTESI : ArrayList<AdisyonListesiBilgileri>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MasaAdisyonListesiAdapter.MasaAdisyonListesiViewHolder>(){
    var ADISYONLAR = _ADISYONLISTESI
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.e("ADISYONBOYUTU",ADISYONLAR.size.toString())
        return ADISYONLAR.size
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MasaAdisyonListesiViewHolder {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MasaAdisyonListesiViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    inner class MasaAdisyonListesiViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    }
}
```

**I expect your answers for the solution. Thank you*

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere

Comment: Recyclerviewadapter does not run a second time @TimCastelijns

Comment: that is not a question